# Sequential call CompletableFutures

Tags: java, concurrency, promise, volatile, completable-future

I have infinite queue of promises(completablefuture) as an input.
The goal is to run promises one by one till condition fulfilled on the result and stop processing and return result from current promise.

My iterative solution looks like that:

```
volatile boolean shouldKeepReading = true;
....
CompletableFuture<Integer> result = promisesQueue.poll().get();

while (shouldKeepReading) {
      result = result.thenCompose(res -> {
        if (conditionPass(res)) {
          shouldKeepReading = false;
          return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0));
        } else {
          if (shouldKeepReading) {
            return promisesQueue.poll().get();
          } else {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0));
          }
        }
      });
```

1. I used infinite loop with volatile flag to control processing. Volatile guarantee memory visibility to all readers. Once condition met control flag will be set to false in order to stop processing.
2. I used double check before read next item.

```
if (shouldKeepReading) {
            return promisesQueue.poll().get();
```

The code seems works correct but noticed that volatile keyword is not needed here, it doesn't change the processing. Why ? Have I miss something ?
Do you see any problems with that code ?

Comment: @Kayaman how do you now that the initial future returned by `promisesQueue.poll().get()` is already completed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HotSpot JVM is rather conservative. It’s too easy to reproducibly see writes made by other threads as side effect of other, unrelated, reads and writes with stronger memory guarantees.

For example, in your case `thenCompose` checks the completion status of the future whereas the implementation specific caller of the function will change the completion status. This may appear to have the desired effect even when the status is “not completed” in which case there’s no formal *happens-before* relationship or when actually calling `thenApply` on the next chained future which also doesn’t establish a *happens-before* relationship as it’s a different variable.

In other words, it may appear to work with this JVM implementation without `volatile` but is not guaranteed, so you should never rely on such behavior.

Even worse, your code is not guaranteed to work even with `volatile`.
The basic shape of your code is

```java
CompletableFuture<Integer> result = …

while (shouldKeepReading) {
  result = result.thenCompose(…);
}
```

which implies that as long as the initial future is not already completed, this loop may chain an arbitrary number of dependent actions until the completion of the dependency chain manages to catch up. The system load caused by this loop may even prevent the chain from catching up, until encountering an `OutOfMemoryError`.

As long as the completion chain manages to catch up, you don’t notice a difference, as all chained actions evaluate to the same result, zero, as soon as `shouldKeepReading` became `false`.

Since the original future originates from `promisesQueue.poll().get()` outside the scope, we may simulate a higher workload by inserting a small delay. Then, add a counter to see what the end result doesn’t tell, e.g.

```java
AtomicInteger chainedOps = new AtomicInteger();

CompletableFuture<Integer> result = promisesQueue.poll().get();
result = result.whenCompleteAsync(
    (x,y) -> LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(2)));

while(shouldKeepReading) {
    result = result.thenCompose(res -> {
        chainedOps.incrementAndGet();
        if(conditionPass(res)) {
            shouldKeepReading = false;
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0);
        } else {
            if (shouldKeepReading) {
                return promisesQueue.poll().get();
            } else {
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0);
            }
        }
    });
}
result.join();
System.out.println(chainedOps.get() + " chained ops");
```

On my machine, the loop easily chains more than five million actions, even when `conditionPass` returns `true` in the first.

The solution is quite simple. Use neither a flag variable nor a loop

```java
result = result.thenCompose(new Function<Integer, CompletionStage<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Integer> apply(Integer res) {
        // for testing, do chainedOps.incrementAndGet();
        return conditionPass(res)? CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0):
            promisesQueue.poll().get().thenCompose(this);
      }
});
```

This calls `thenCompose` only when the condition is not fulfilled, hence, never chains more actions than necessary. Since it requires the function itself to be chained via `thenCompose(this)`, the lambda has to be replaced by an anonymous inner class. If you don’t like this, you may resort to a recursive solution

```java
CompletableFuture<Integer> retryPoll() {
    CompletableFuture<Integer> result = promisesQueue.poll().get();
    return result.thenComposeAsync(res ->
        conditionPass(res)? CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0): retryPoll());
}
```

It’s remarkably simple here, as the retry doesn’t depend on the result of the previous evaluation (you’d need to introduce parameters otherwise), but on the changes `promisesQueue.poll().get()` makes to the program’s state.

This method uses `thenComposeAsync` to avoid deep recursions if there is a large number of already completed futures whose result is rejected by `conditionPass`. If you know for sure that `conditionPass` will succeed after a rather small amount of retries, you can change `thenComposeAsync` to `thenCompose`.

Comment: Thanks @Holger for this great post. Although I was aware of recursive way I wanted to try with iterative way. I am a bit surprised that volatile doesn't work here(I use only sequential version thenCompse, so no additional chains here while waiting for competition ). But why exactly happens-before relationship doesn't work here ? Do you mean that volatile variable is different because threads work on local copy of it ?

Comment: People often reason about `volatile` like “if thread A writes … and thread B reads … and then …” but declaring a variable `volatile` does not mean that thread `B`’s read will wait for thread A’s write. So thread B can read the old value a million times before thread A ever gets to write the new value. As said in the answer, when the system has no spare core, thread B’s polling of the variable may even prevent thread A from running (and hence performing the write). Today, most systems switch preemptively, so the write will happen eventually, but B’s loop still can cause a significant delay.

Comment: Ok, I assumed I have here full synchronous sequential chain because of thenCompose but in fact is isn't because my tasks from queue are run in async way. And during the time of execution a dependent action are chained in main loop. From my testing it tours out that at least flag coordination(conditionPass) works good here. I have never got the additional call for the next queue element once stop condition is met. Yes, but in total this concept is not acceptable because of this uncontrolled additional chains of actions.